# Semaphore Implementation: Monitor vs. Sleeping Barber, huge performance difference

Tags: c#, performance, locking, semaphore, monitor

In my computer science class we had several different implementation of a Semaphore. Two of those were done by using a normal Monitor implementation and one using a Sleeping Barber implementation:

Monitor Implementation:

```
class Semaphore {
int s; object mutex = new object();
public Semaphore(int n) { s = n; }

public void P() 
{
        lock (mutex) 
        {
          while (s == 0) Monitor.Wait(mutex); 
          s--; 
        }
}
public void V() 
{
        lock (mutex) 
        {
          s++; Monitor.Pulse(mutex); 
        }
}

}
```

Sleeping Barber Implentation:

```
class Semaphore {
int s; object mutex = new object();
public Semaphore (int n) { s = n; }

public void P () 
{
        lock(mutex) 
        {
            s--; 
            if (s < 0) Monitor.Wait(mutex);
        }
}
public void V () 
{
        lock(mutex) 
        { 
            s++;
            if (s <= 0) Monitor.Pulse(mutex);
        }
}

}
```

Both implementation seem very similar to me. The only difference I see is that s becomes negative in the sleeping barber implementation and in the Monitor implementation it stays at s=0 until V() is executed.

But measured there was a huge difference(data from the presentation slide):

```
Semaphore Type     Time (ms)
Monitor                 7549
Monitor (Barber)      109598
```

What's a possible explanation for those huge different perfomance outcomes?

Comment: Where does s normally start at? If s starts at 0, Pulse is never invoked in the second implementation of V()

Comment: @Me.Name: An example if s starts at 0: s.P() waits and s=-1. Then s.V(), so s becomes 0 and Pulse is invoked. I don't know what example you mean that doesn't work. Could you say what you meant exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the reason for this is due to the `while` in the first solution, versus the second that just uses an `if`. The `while` will repeatedly check the condition, causing waiting to occur until a time slice occurs.